# How to raise domain Event When I don't want to share actual domain model

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement DDD in my small project but Not able to understand how to raise domain event in below case.

**Account Domain**

```
public class Account : BaseEntity
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public int OTP { get; set; }

    public Account()
    {
    }

    public Account(string phoneNumber, short otp)
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.OTP = otp;
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        PartitionKey = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

**Account Service**

```
public async Task<bool> GenerateOTP(string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (phoneNumber.Length != 10)
            throw new ArgumentException(ApplicationConstraint.InvalidNumber);

        var otp = Convert.ToInt16(new Random().Next(1000, 9999));
        var account = new Account(phoneNumber, otp);
        await this.accountRepository.AddEntity(account);
        return true;
    }
```

**Account Repository** Azure Storage table is my database

```
public virtual async Task AddEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
        await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }
```

I want to raise domain event only when data get saved in the database. For a workaround, I'm calling messaging service from account service.

Comment: What is the domain event you want to raise? I don't see why you're being forced to share the domain model in the first place. What goes into an event is something you control. Maybe rephrase the question a bit? Or provide some more details?

Comment: It is a classic two-phase commit issue, which has nothing to do with Domain-Driven Design. It doesn't matter really who is responsible for publishing events, using the app service is fine, but if you won't ensure atomicity of this operation, you'll get into trouble really quickly.

Comment: @SavvasKleanthous Once account data get saved in DB, I want to send message in Queue so other subscriber services can process the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limited information provided, one option would be to create an `AccountCreated` event, (or an `EntityCreated` event if this is a cross-cutting concern) and publish it through some bus where consumers can asynchronousle receive it and do any subsequent processing needed.

The event need not use domain entities, and it can contain the information/data necessary to do any subsequent processing without the need to access a shared db (and as such adhering to DDD & microservice guidelines).

----Edit----

In the above I assumed that this is an established system and Azure storage isn't something that can change. Publishing an event, and handling it is pretty simple, but there are some things you need to be aware of. In general, you have 3 options here:

1. Publishing right after saving isn't wrong. It's simple way to do it, and (if you adopt an event-first methodology) you can do it in a generic way across your entities, minimal work. However, you need to be concious of how to deal with errors. Specifically, the issue is that if you store the entity first, before publishing the event, and then the process crashes for whatever reason, the event may be missed, so later workflows will not kick-off. If you do the reverse (publish then store), you run the risk of double-publishing the event. In this case you have two options:

   1. If you store-then-publish: just accept the (really rare) possiblity of not publishing an event. This is something you need to speak to the business, and you can minigate the severity by logging the event before trying to save the entity.
   2. If you publish-then-store: (you'll need to do this if the cost of fixing any issues ad-hoc are too great) you can fix the problem by having your consumers check the id of the incoming message if they ever have processed it before and reject it if they did OR make the process idempotent (if possible), meaning that doing the process twice isn't a problem
2. Using event sourcing. This isn't difficult in my opinion, but obviously it's an overhead if this is a a simple application, and while not difficult, it *does* need a significant amount of reading up if you're not familiar with it. If this is a non-trivial application, event sourcing can help a lot, because observers can just observe the events in the buffer and respond to that (so not need to explicitly publish the changes).
3. Append the event in a separate table within the same transaction where you're storing the entity, and use the [outbox pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) implementation (publish those events from a separate service, marking them as published once they've been published). Honestly, the pattern shown on that is a bit simplistic, and there are a lot of tricky and small complexities, so prefer to use an existing one if you can find.

Honestly, if you can get away with 1.1, do that. It's simple and problems only very rarely appear. Just log the operation before you do it so that you can manually do it in the rare case of issues.

Comment: If I'm raising domain event (AccountCreated) from AccountService, after saving data in database, Is it the correct way?

Comment: @PankajRawat I updated the answer. Please consider accepting the answer if it answers your quesion